# regex doesn't capture an optional group

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to capture words that may have some text between, for example, I need to capture Microsoft and office if they exist in this text

```
Microsoft have lunched her product office in 2003
```

I use this regex

```
(?mix:(microsoft).{1,100}(office)?.{0,100}(2003)?)
```

but it doesn't capture office. It considers it one of the 100 characters in between.

Comment: It may not help (because `office` is optional`) but try `{-1,100}` for your counts which (according to VIM's help) means grab as few repetitions as posible.

Comment: @TripeHound: you're talking about laziness, but this alone won't be enough to solve the issue. Also this pattern is usually invalid, you would generally use `{0,100}?` instead.

Comment: @Safouen: what language are you using? Why the `x` modifier? If the words are fixed, wouldn't it be easier to just check whether each of them are in the string, seprately?

Comment: What should `microsoft 2003 office` match?

Comment: @Robin I'm currently using ruby, yes I can search for every word on its own but I don't need the words to bee so far away from each other

Comment: @Robin - As I said, I wasn't sure if laziness would be enough, and wasn't in a position to try, so was just throwing it out as something to try.  Thanks for the correction/clarification.

Comment: @Safouen: so what you *actually* want to do is match special words clustered together? I'm don't think regex is the best tool for that... I don't know ruby so I can't help with the code, but I believe it would be easier to get the indexes of each word in your string, then work on these to find which are close to each other

Comment: Are you trying to capture words in any order? E.g. `office` must come after `microsoft` but before `2003`. If you just want to capture selected words, you may try something like `"Microsoft have lunched her product office in 2003".scan(/(microsoft|office|\d\d(\d\d)?)/i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safouen, here are two options for you.

First, if you want to specify a max of 100 characters in between as before, use this:

```
(?mi)(microsoft).{1,100}?(?:(office).{1,100}?(?:(2003)|$)|$)
```

It will capture microsoft, and optionally office and 2003 if present. There are various ways of writing this, this is just the one that came to mind.

Second, if you don't care how many characters are in between, just substitute a `*` in place of the `{1,100}`:

```
(?mi)(microsoft).*?(?:(office).*?(?:(2003)|$)|$)
```

To examine the matches in Ruby, it could look like this:

```
subject.scan(/(?mi)(microsoft).*?(?:(office).*?(?:(2003)|$)|$)/) {|result|
    # If the regex has capturing groups, result is an array with the text matched by each group (but without the overall match)
    # If the regex has no capturing groups, result is a string with the overall regex match
}
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: and is there a way to have them not in oreder for example office before microsoft

Comment: @safouen Yes. For instance, if you are sure you want microsoft, and optionally the others, in any order, you can use three lookaheads: `\A(?=.*?(Microsoft))(?=.*?(office))(?=.*?\s+(\d+)).*?Microsoft`

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
regexp = /\A(Microsoft).*?(office)?(?:\s+\w+\s+)?(\d+)?\Z/i
```

http://rubular.com/r/K8SsjJcfjT